# How to locate dropdown element when the visible text on drop down box has different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I dont want to click on "OK" which is visible on screen instead only want to click on down arrow to pop the list.
Any option i tried gave me " element not found" for down arrow.
When I mouse hover on "OK" it shows a different class and when I move hover to down arrow, one extra bit of statement gets added in class section of OK.

I have tried everything I could think to locate the down arrow and be able to click it but nothing has worked so far.
[image]

Since I can only add oneimgae..

class after mouse hover on drop dwn arrow=

```
class="yui-button yui-split-button yui-split-button-activeoption yui-split-button-hoveroption"
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: Have you tried with `//span[starts-with(@class,'yui-button yui-split-button yui-split-button-activeoption yui-split-button-hover')]`?

Comment: @supputuri I get the unable to locate element error. Also, this same class is for 3 more drop downs. and the ID for all of them keeps changing.

Comment: I would first check if `//button[.='OK']` is not throwing nosuchelement exception? If yes, then try this `//button[.='OK']/ancestor::span[starts-with(@class,'yui-button yui-split-button yui-split-button-activeoption yui-split-button-hover')]`